# Changing a href to laravel anchor tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my regular code in the blade

```
<a href="<?php echo url();?>/blog/<?php echo $Blog->id;?>">{{ $Blog->BlogTitle }}</a>
```

I want to do something like

```
{{ HTML::link('http://test.com', null, array('id' => 'linkid'))}}
```

I mean i want to do it in the laravel way..

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
{{ HTML::link(url().'/blog'.$Blog->id, $Blog->BlogTitle)}}
```